# ember (+ ember-auth) linkTo loggedIn user profile

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

To get straight to the point, I have an app with a profile accessible like that:

```
this.resource('user', {path: '/user/:user_id'});
```

This can accessed from visitors and (logged in users). Now I also have a menu-bar which has, only for logged in users, a link to the user-profile (so that would be /user/:loggedin-user_id). I am using ember-auth to authenticate the user and ember data for my models.
The problem here seems to be {{linkTo 'user'}} doesn't work, because for one user that should link to /user/28, for the next one to /user/15. Simply to his/her own profile. I kinda get that it doesn't work, because how should ember know what ID to display (though yes, I don't understand the underlying reasons fully).
Ember-Auth does provide App.Auth.get('userId') to get the Id of the currently logged in user, but I don't really know how I can tell ember to know that as well.

So what I had to do know is setting the link manually via

```
<a {{bindAttr href="App.loggedInUser"}}>
```

where-as this variable gets set to the right url in the Application controller with App.Auth.get('userId'). This works, but is obviously quite a hack.

Is there any 'ember' way of solving that?

Comment: I am not sure I follow completely. Doesn't `linkTo 'user'` always give a link to your `user` route, like `/user` or `/profile`?

Comment: Sorry, I realised that it wasn't phrased that well. Hope it is more clear now. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ember-auth](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/) dev here.

Straight to solution:

First, ask ember-auth to load the user current user model. Assuming that your user model is called `App.User`, and it implements `App.User.find(id)`.

```
App.Auth = Ember.Auth.create
  # ...
  userModel: 'App.User' # default null
  # pass the string, not a class App.User

# access the current user model
# as with all things ember, this is loaded asynchronously
App.Auth.get('user')
```

(copied from the [docs](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/).)

Next, pass this dynamic model to your handlebars links:

```
{{#linkTo 'user' App.Auth.user}}Link To Current User{{/link}}
```

Or otherwise - e.g. make it a binding to `App.Auth.get('user')`, etc.

Just in case, (js) `App.get('foo')` is equivalent to ember-handlebars `App.foo`.

Comment: Ahh ok, then I was halfway there. That works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `user` route has a dynamic segment. You can pass the `user` model to the `linkTo` and the anchor will point to that route for different users depending on the id of user model passed.

```
{{linkTo 'user' userObj}}Profile{{/linkTo}}
```

The model passed can be plain object with an id and the default serialization would still work. So if you wrap `App.Auth.get('userId')` into a object with an id you won't need a full model object.

Here's an example [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ofareh/1/edit).